# Can no longer debug logic apps azure api action - Swagger definition currently unavailable for this option

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have a logic app that calls azure app using a logic app azure api action.
It passes some parameters to the api.
When i last looked at this some months ago, i could see the parameters, and even edit the action if required.

Now if i look at the action, either in run history or when editing the action in the browser i get the error: Swagger definition is currently unavailable for this operation.

It is affecting POST and PUT operations. GET seems unaffected.

[image]

Is anyone aware of anything that has changed with Azure API Management or Logic APP's Azure API Management Action?

Comment: Did you check the API Management operation? Is it still working if you test it in the developer portal?

Comment: yes, if i test the API with required parameters from the API Management blade, it functions as expected

Answer (score 1):

We found a resolution to this.
Something has changed within the Logic Apps API management Action, and it now requires that POST & PUT operations within Azure API require a sample of the message body that will be sent.

Once we added in a sample, we could again expand the Azure API actions in the logic app and see all the various params.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @wilson_smyth inputs

> Swagger definition is currently unavailable for this operation. This could result into errors when saving.

The above error occurs when the Api is not fully connected.

I followed the below steps which gave me the expected results to avoid the given error.

- For demonstration purposes, I have created an Azure Function with [Http Trigger](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-http-trigger-azure-function-in-azure-portal/#:%7E:text=Create%20the%20Http%20Trigger%20Azure%20Function%20in%20Azure,options%20are%20there.%20...%206%20Step%206%20).

  [image]
- Then I have created Api in Azure Api Management as mentioned in the above Azure Function. Tested it which gave me the output "Hello, Azure. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. "

  [image]
- I have created a  **Azure Logic Apps (Consumption)**  and selected the  [Azure Api management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#how-do-custom-apis-differ-from-custom-connectors)  which was created earlier.

  [image]
- Select the post method with parameters like authentication type, value and subscription key. Save the application and run it.

  [image]

Comment: This does not help with existing api management instances called in logic apps, that worked up to recently but now do not.